# Is the order guaranteed when iterating an array with keys?

Tags: javascript

Is the order guaranteed when iterating an array with keys?

My code:

```
const data = {};
data["a"] = 1;
data["c"] = 2;
data["b"] = 3;

for (const id in data) {
    console.log(data[id]);
}
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
```

Is the result guaranteed to always be the same?

Comment: no, the order is not guaranteed

Comment: In modern environments, yes, [for all methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013) that iterate over keys. @MisterJojo Yes it is - it's an ES2020 thing, see the link

Comment: I suppose you look for a 100% guarantee, in any environment, no ?

Comment: In a single word, NO

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava See my link - it *is* guaranteed by the specification, and all environments have been doing so for many years anyway